# Remove duplicate rows in sql database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, duplicates, row

I have a table with the following fields :

```
`contract`, `title`, `category`, `reglementation`, `company`, `role`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `creation_date`, `update_date`, `created_by`, `updated_by`,`context`,`hash`,`accept_schedule`,`need_timecard`
```

and , I need to remove rows with same contract and end_date is null , but with the small value of  start_date

this query returns duplicate rows , it returns 9000

```
select contract, count(*) 
from n_h_associate_occupation o 
where end_date is null 
group by o.contract 
having count(*) > 1;
```

is there a way to delete those rows ? PLease help

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option which should work on all versions of MySQL:

```
SELECT o1.*
FROM n_h_associate_occupation o1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT contract, MIN(start_date) AS min_start_date
    FROM n_h_associate_occupation
    WHERE end_date IS NULL
    GROUP BY contract
) o2
    ON o1.contract = o2.contract AND
       o1.start_date = o2.min_start_date
WHERE
    o1.end_date IS NULL;
```

This assumes that you want to *retain* the row(s) having the smallest start date, should a given contract have multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

If for each value of `contract` you want to get rid of all the rows with the smallest `start_date` values, that is keep only the row with the maximum `start_date`, for those rows where `end_date` is `null`, then:

```
delete o from
n_h_associate_occupation o join
( 
select contract, max(start_date) as max_start_date
from n_h_associate_occupation
where end_date is null
group by contract
having count(*) > 1
) sq
on o.contract = sq.contract and o.end_date is null and o.start_date <> sq.max_start_date
```

[See Db Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oGYka4RNjjk7tw9qK9S8iQ/0)

If you wanted to keep the row with the *smallest* `start_date` (it's not entirely clear from your question), then:

```
delete o from
n_h_associate_occupation o join
( 
select contract, min(start_date) as min_start_date
from n_h_associate_occupation
where end_date is null
group by contract
having count(*) > 1
) sq
on o.contract = sq.contract and o.end_date is null and o.start_date <> sq.min_start_date
```